# Insert into MySQL table new row with one column of the same value as auto_increment primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `data`:

```
id | field1 | field2
--------------------
1  | text_f  | 1
2  | sth     | 2
...
```

and the `id` was created with `auto_increment` option.

I wonder, how I can insert a new row to that table with the respect that `filed2` should have the same value as `id`.

Of course I could use three queries:

1. `INSERT INTO "data" (field1, field2) VALUES ("some text", 0)`
2. `SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID()`
3. `UPDATE "data" SET field2 = @id WHERE id = @id`

But is there an option to make in with a single query?

Comment: the other alternative is to use a trigger before insert.

Comment: @koriander Indeed. But it's also somehow "complicated" (complex) solution for that task - to involve a trigger for inserting an single row. Still, it's some alternative.

Comment: triggers are ideal to put constraints to your data.